# Access scoped Material theme in custom component

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, scss-mixins

In Material, you can [define scoped themes](https://v15.material.angular.io/guide/theming#scoping-style-customizations) to style just a portion of your app:

```scss
// config.scss
$my-special-theme: mat.define-light-theme(/*omitted*/));
.my-scope {
  @include mat.button-color($my-special-theme);
}
```

```html
<!-- container.component.html -->
<section class="my-scope">
  <button mat-button color="primary">Foo</button>
  <app-bar></app-bar>
</section>
```

That button will be styled using the primary color from the special (scoped) theme.

What I'd like to know is: how can I use the same mechanism for my custom components? What I currently have is:

```scss
// bar.component.scss
@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use 'config' as config;

$color-config: mat.get-color-config(config.$my-special-theme);
$primary: map.get($color-config, 'primary');

:host {
  background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary, 100);
}
```

But that means I need to specify the theme twice to use it:

1. In `bar.component.scss` with `mat.get-color-config(config.$my-special-theme)` (explicitly styles my custom component)
2. In `container.component.html` with `class="my-scope"` (implicitly styles nested Material components)

How can I get my custom components to use the scoped styles, like Material? I think I'd rather not have to define a mixin to be included globally in `config.scss`, because currently my components define their styles in their own `.scss` files — but I'm open to suggestion.

Initial research direction: I'm trying to find a way to get the current (scoped) theme in the custom component rather than hard-coding it:

```scss
$color-config: mat.get-color-config(???);
```

But I suspect that isn't going to be possible.